# SQL SERVER update or insert after left join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, left-join, insert-update

I have a Table `Animals`

```
Id | Name     | Count | -- (other columns not relevant)
1  | horse    | 11   
2  | giraffe  | 20
```

I want to try to insert or update values from a CSV string

Is it possible to do something like the following in 1 query?

```
;with results as
(
 select * from
 (
  values ('horse'), ('giraffe'), ('lion')
 )
  animal_csv(aName)
  left join animals on
  animals.[Name] = animal_csv.aName
)
update results 
set
[Count] = 1 + animals.[Count]
-- various other columns are set here
where Id is not null

--else
--insert into results ([Name], [Count]) values (results.aName, 1) 
-- (essentially Where id is null)
```

Comment: Let's start with a complete script that has DDL and sample data. Then add what results you expect from this experiment. And note that there is not "CSV" about your issue. Your  derived table named animal_csv is simple a table value constructor for a table containing 3 hardcoded rows. That terminology will confuse everyone - don't use it. Your left join is also confusing - 'lion' does not exist in your actual table so what should happen with that name?

Comment: in my code the `animal_csv` comes from a CSV file which i process to get the above string. `lion` should get added with a count of  `1` as it doesn't exist in the `animals` table yet.

Comment: It appears that you are looking for the [`merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're looking for is a table variable or temporary table rather than a common table expression.

If I understand your problem correctly, you are building a result set based on data you're getting from a CSV, merging it by incrementing values, and then returning that result set.

As I read your code, it looks as if your results would look like this:

```
aName    | Id | Name    | Count
horse    | 1  | horse   | 12
giraffe  | 2  | giraffe | 21
lion     |    |         |
```

I think what you're looking for in your final result set is this:

```
Name     | Count
horse    | 12
giraffe  | 21
lion     | 1
```

First, you can get from your csv and table to a resultset in a single CTE statement:

```
;WITH animal_csv AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('horse'),('giraffe'), ('lion')) a(aName))
SELECT ISNULL(Name, aName) Name
,   CASE WHEN [Count] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 1 + [Count] END [Count] 
    FROM animal_csv
        LEFT JOIN animals
            ON Name = animal_csv.aName
```

Or, if you want to build your resultset using a table variable:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
  Name  VARCHAR(30)
, Count INT
)

;WITH animal_csv AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('horse'),('giraffe'), ('lion')) a(aName))
INSERT @Results
SELECT ISNULL(Name, aName) Name
,   CASE WHEN [Count] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 1 + [Count] END [Count] 
    FROM animal_csv
        LEFT JOIN animals
            ON Name = animal_csv.aName

SELECT * FROM @results
```

Or, if you just want to use a temporary table, you can build it like this (temp tables are deleted when the connection is released/closed or when they're explicitly dropped):

```
;WITH animal_csv AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('horse'),('giraffe'), ('lion')) a(aName))
SELECT ISNULL(Name, aName) Name
,   CASE WHEN [Count] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 1 + [Count] END [Count] 
    INTO #results
    FROM animal_csv
        LEFT JOIN animals
            ON Name = animal_csv.aName

SELECT * FROM #results
```